# Determine if file is hidden or deleted

Tags: windows, security

When I open MSConfig and look at all the applications set to run on startup there is a suspicious file set to run at startup. I have disabled the `.exe` not to run at startup but I want to delete the `.exe` as well.

From MSConfig I can see that the `.exe` sits in `%APPDATA%` folder but I am unable to see the .exe when I navigate to the folder in Windows Explorer. Is it possible the .exe has already been deleted(it may have been a legitimate app that I uninstalled at some point)? Can a `.exe` that does not exist be shown in MSConfig?

**How can I delete the .exe?**

Note: I know C++ WinAPI and I have attempted to find the file using `FindFirstFileEx();` (I'm a Admin User) and also tried open it with `CreateFile();` but both say "Cannot find path specified". That could mean that the file doesn't exist but could that also mean that the file permissions are set to `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN`? I've also tried `SetFileAttributes` to `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` but it gives the same error? *Any ideas on what I should do to confirm whether the file exists?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command prompt to open the file in Notepad:

```
notepad %APPDATA%\SomePath\SomeFile.Ext
```

If it doesn't exist, it'll tell you.